# How could I add apache asp and python (on linux not windows)?

Tags: python, linux, apache, asp-classic

I currently have a Linux server with [Apache::ASP](http://www.apache-asp.org/) installed that uses Perl.

Is it possible to create an Active Server Page on a Linux Apache Server using Python (in lieu of Perl)?

I have seen an IIS add [Python](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/) or [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) as a .NET to make ASP, what about a Linux server using Apache?

Now I see [ActivePython](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/ASP_and_Python.html) may or may not have this option. It seems when the windows distribution is installed, it could be possible to do something like:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE = Python%>
<html>
<body>
<% 
test = 'Hello World'
if (true):
    Response.Write(test)
%>
</body>
</html>
```

But again, this seems to be available for just the Windows version.

Comment: My guess is probably not.  ActiveState make Perl and Python distributions tailored to run on Windows.  Anyway, so much of ASP involves accessing COM components which are only available to Windows that I you might not be able to do that much with it in a UNIX environment.  There are other ways of embedding python in HTML.  https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating

Answer (score 0):

I'd say most likely not - at least not using `Apache::ASP`, as it seems expressedly designed to work with `mod_perl`.

You may want to look into [Oracle iPlanet Web Server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/iplanetwebserver-098726.html) (Formerly SunONE, formerly... a lot of different names). It's more of a replacement for Apache itself - but as far as I can tell, you should be able to use any FastCGI language.